# Perl - Internal File (create and execute)

Tags: perl, file, execute

I have a quick question about creating files with perl and executing them.  I wanted to know if it was possible to generate a file using perl (I actually need a .bat script) and then execute this file internally to the program.  I know I can create files, and I have with perl, however, I'm wanting to do this internally to the program.  So, what I want it to do is actually create a batch script internally to the program (no file is actually written to the disk, everything remains in memory, or the perl program), and then once it completes the writing of the file, I'd like to be able to actually execute this file, and then discard the file it just wrote.  I'm basically trying to have it create a batch script on the fly, so that I can just have output text files from the output of the script, rather than creating the batch script on disk, then executing it, and then deleting the batch file from disk when its done.

Can this be done and how would I go about doing this?

Regards,
Drew

Comment: Why do you want to write a Perl program that writes a batch program to do some processing instead of doing whatever processing from your Perl program?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569833/what-are-the-reasons-to-use-dos-batch-programs-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a batch script? Perhaps everything you want to do can be done directly from Perl or invoked directly by Perl via its `system` command.

If a batch script is essential, what's wrong with creating a temporary file for the script and then executing it with `system`? See [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html), which will even delete the temporary file automatically after you are done.

If the virtual-batch-file strategy is unavoidable, you might be able to leverage the `/C` and maybe `/S` options of `cmd`. Something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @batch_commands = (
    'dir',
    q{echo "Make sure quoting isn't busted"},
    'ipconfig',
);

# Use & or &&, depending on your needs. Run `cmd /?` for details.
my $virtual_bat_file = join " &\n", @batch_commands;

system "cmd /C $virtual_bat_file";
```

But this feels very wrong. There has to be a better way to accomplish whatever the larger goal of your application is. By the way, when you run `cmd /?` to learn about `/C`, `/S`, and `&` vs. `&&`, you'll quickly appreciate how terrible it is in the *Land of Batch*. Stay away if at all possible.

Comment: FM thanks for your efforts.  Let me continue to explain.

The reason I want it this way, is because the batch script that needs to be created, is dynamically built.  So basically, based on a directory full of files, in my case, TIF files, which builds a set of commands that get information from these tif files, and then exports a text file with that raw data.  Right now, the .batch script is created, outputted to a file, and then remains on the drive.

Comment: ...Continuing ...

I know I can easily remove the file at the end of execution, however, I don't want that.  I actually want it to build the command set, and execute the script, and never actually create the batch file to disk.  

The batch script is all dynamic data, and in the format of:

tiffcommand tifffile.tif
tiffcommand tifffile2.tif
etc etc...

The data is always going to change and that's why I want it to be dynamically created and executed on the fly.

Comment: Most temp file modules (IIRC, including File::Temp) have an option to automagically remove the created temp file once the program exists, or temp file object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

open the file; create the contents; close the file; execute the file (with system(), for example); remove the file.